# Get exact cell clicked in nested html table

Tags: html, html-table

In one of my pages, I am using an example of editable html table from this link: http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-an-editable-html-table-with-jquery/27425, which works without any issues and when I click on a cell in the table, it changes it to text box.

However, I had to change the layout of my page where, I had to place the sample mentioned above within another html table (nested).

Now the problem is when I click on the cell, it does not identify the child table, which has the data and I want to click but it clicks on the cell of the parent table, which in this case is the parent table, and holds 2 different tables.

So, what I want you help with is:

1. Get a method to identify the cell of the child table when it is clicked

Or

2. Some way so align two tables on my page to be aligned side by side. Currently I am using the parent table to align my other 2 tables to sit side by side.

if the second option is easier to achieve then, I don't have to change much.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a parent table element to layout elements on your page, just know that this is a deprecated unsemantic practice, as table elements are for tabulating data. You should use the CSS `float` property, which is the convention, see [CSS Floats 101 · An A List Apart Article](http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101) and [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

Refactoring out that parent table should fix your problem. Otherwise you can fix it through modifying the selector in your JavaScript and by assigning the edittable `td` elements with a class (eg. `edittable-cell`) so you're not assigning event listeners to other tables' `td` elements unnecessarily and causing unwanted behaviour elsewhere.

**JavaScript**

```
// Instead of the 'td' selector
$("td").dblclick(function() {
  // .. your code here
});

// Use a more specific selector, eg.:
$('.edittable-cell').dblclick(function() {
  // .. your code here
});
```

If you are semantically nesting tables of data and/or still have this issue, you can try preventing the event from bubbling up to its parent elements.

**JavaScript**

```
$(".edittable-cell").dblclick(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // .. your code here
});
```

Comment: Just a tip when you're not using jQuery and just normal JS you can instead use: `e.stopPropagation ? e.stopPropagation() : e.cancelBubble = true;` to be cross-browser compatible with IE. jQuery takes care of this itself though.